# Can you help me identify why selectize input doesn't render correctly in the R shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Selectize input doesn't render correctly when I run the app on latest version of shiny (1.7.4), DT (0.27) and R (4.2.3). Below is the reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("input1"),
  dataTableOutput("iris")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$input1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("input1", "Select input:", choices = c("one", "two", "three"), multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  output$iris <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(data = iris, filter = 'top')
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get this browser error - Error: Unable to find "selectize-plugin-a11y" plugin and it renders as shown in the image below:
[image]

However it seems to work fine if I remove the argument filter = 'top' from the datatable.

Any idea why this might be happening and any recommended solution?

Comment: Seems like it's a bug according to this [github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3125) which is still opened. So maybe try another widget like `shinyWidgets::pickerInput()` is a workaround solution.

Comment: Also, `selectizeInput("input1",` in the example code is bugged. `selectizeInput("input2",` may be correct. This chapter in [mastering shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#dynamic-basics) should explain it to you.

Comment: thanks @SuNa. I'm using pickerInput for now. Plus I like some of its other features like action box. I used selectizeInput because it can do server side searching. I'm not sure if pickerInput supports that.

Comment: `pickerInput(options = list(\`live-search\` = TRUE))` is what you need. The best part of a html widget is you can always find a live demo given by the creator, like [this](https://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/) :)

Comment: I actually ended up using live-search option but I'm not sure if it does the server side search or on the browser. Server side searching helps when there are several thousand choices. With selectize, you can use options = list(maxOptions = 50), server = TRUE to only show 50 search results even when there are total 20000 values to choose from. Loading all the 20000 values on the browser hangs the browser.